# DMM fault: diode test function not working

Tags: multimeter

I have two Protek 506 digital multimeters, and they both have a fault with their diode testing function.

The first meter **only** displays the word "OPEN" with a voltage of 3.999V below it, and the second one **only** displays the word "Shrt" with a voltage of 0.000.

Neither of the meters will shift from their respective displays, no matter what I do.  I've never used the diode test function before today, and I was surprised that my first meter had this fault, so I tried the second meter, which has barely been used, and was surprised/disappointed that it too should have a faulty diode test function.

- Is this a particular problem with the Protek 506?
- What would be causing the problem?
- Can it be fixed?

Comment: How did you test it? What diodes you used?

Comment: I think the problem is not with multimeters. do you have other diodes or BJT to test?

Comment: Without knowing how you tested it, we aren't able to say much. Add a diagram of how you connected them etc.

Comment: Thanks Justme, emre iris and Puffafish for your responses.  The problem is not with the testing of a diode, the problem exists as soon as the diode test function is selected, being that the meters do not change from what is displayed.  In the case of the first meter, shorting the leads should display "Shrt" with "0.000V", but there is no change from "OPEn"/3.999.  The second meter comes on displaying "Shrt"/0.000, when it should read "OPEn"/3.999.  I have the circuit schematic for this meter, and there appears to be a couple of components to check.  Very odd situation!

Comment: The second Protek 506 is now working normally!  Basically, with the first DMM, it is normal, when selecting diode test function, with leads not touching anything, that "OPEn" is displayed, and if the leads are shorted together, the display will show "Shrt".  But in this case the display doesn't change from "OPEn" to "Shrt" when the leads are shorted out.